# Angular2 RC5 Mock Activated Route Params

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-testing

I need to be able to mock the activated route parameters to be able to test my component.

Here's my best attempt so far, but it doesn't work.

```
{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { params: [ { 'id': 1 } ] } },
```

The ActivatedRoute is used in the actual component like this:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.stateId = +params['id'];

    this.stateService.getState(this.stateId).then(state => {
        this.state = state;
    });
});
```

The error I get with my current attempt is simply:

`TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.route.params.subscribe')`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your mock must reflect the object it's replacing. You `.subscribe` because it returns an observable, not just the object, so your mock value should too:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

...

{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { 'params': Observable.from([{ 'id': 1 }]) } }
```

Comment: Hi i was just wondering How can I use this provide activated route inside my it() block?

Comment: @BhushanGadekar what do you mean? It's just an object, you can assign the `useValue` to a name.

Comment: @jonsharpe can you edit your answer for it() block.. I have set pageId from route params, and i want to check if after ngOnInit() gets called, my pageId is populated or not?

Comment: @BhushanGadekar you literally just have to extract and name that object within your tests, actually only the inner `{ 'id': 1 }`. You really should be able to figure it out.

Comment: This almost works,.... I get cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined. Probably because our Observable goes out of scope. Do you have a solution for that @jonrsharpe ? :)

Comment: @MagnusGud you've given nowhere near enough information to answer that, I don't even know what you're trying to unsubscribe from, or where.

Comment: Sorry about that jon. I have the following scenario: 
in ngOnInit Im doing this: 
 this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => //and so on.
and then in 
ngOnDestroy Im tearing down the subscription:
this.subscription.unsubscribe();

what happens is that subscription is now undefined. I don't really get why. What im going to do is to make my code more robust, and check if subscription is undefined before tearing it down. Then it should work :)

Comment: @MagnusGud I don't know why either, that's probably unrelated to the mocking, as you're getting a real `Observable`. Once you have isolated the issue, ask a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: @MagnusGud I have a feeling that you need to add a conditional to your `ngOnDestroy()` method. Like 

    `ngOnDestroy() {
      if (this.sub) { this.sub.unsubscribe() }
    }`

Answer (score 10):

Answer given by @jonrsharpe allows you to mock `params`, but those params would be the same in every test.

If you want to be able to change the `params`, to set it at the start of a test, you can do it like this:

At the top:

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  (...)
  let params: Subject<Params>;
  (...)
```

in `beforeEach` (the `async` one - where you have `imports`, `providers` etc.):

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  params = new Subject<Params>();
  (...)
```

in `providers`:

```
  (...)
  {
    provide: ActivatedRoute,
    useValue: {
      params: params
    }
  }
  (...)
```

and then in test:

```
it('someTest', () => {
  params.next({'id': '123'});
  fixture.detectChanges();
  (...)
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

Be sure to call `fixture.detectChanges` after `params.next`.

This means you should remove `fixture.detectChanges` from `beforeEach` and add it to every test.

Comment: and if I'm using queryParams inside the snapshot?