# Angular 2 Testing Error Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, utilities

I'm trying to test a component.ts:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
...
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        let id = +params['id'];
...
}
```

the spec.ts code below:

```
describe('MyDetailComponent', () => {
    beforeEach( async(() => {
    addMatchers();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ MaterialModule, FormsModule ],
            declarations: [ MyDetailComponent ],
            providers: [
                ...
                { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: RequestOptionsStub },
                { provide: ActivatedRoute,      useClass: RouterStub },
                { provide: Location }, 
                { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
                AppSettings,
                Http,
                ConnectionBackend,
                Jsonp
            ]
        })
    .compileComponents()
    .then(createComponent);
}));
```

and I'm getting the error:
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

How to fix this?

Comment: There also was a good suggestion to add RouterTestingModule which helped solve the issue as well:     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [ 
                    ...
                    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
                        { path: '...', component: MyDetailComponent }
                    ])  
                ],

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in [Angular2 RC5 Mock Activated Route Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39376840/angular2-rc5-mock-activated-route-params) :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

...

{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { 'params': Observable.from([{ 'id': 1 }]) } }
```